# How to check if variable not null before adding it as object property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have this code:

```
let resetElementOnLiveEdit = null
    if(liveEdit){
      if(!profile in liveEdit)
        resetElementOnLiveEdit = {
          [Object.keys(liveEdit)[0]]: liveEdit[Object.keys(liveEdit)[0]]
        }
    }
```

Please, pay attention to the resetElementOnLiveEdit variable. By default it's **null**, then i have conditions.

Then i'm trying to set state like this:

```
this.setState({
      profiles: {
        ...this.state.profiles,
        [profile]: profileCopy,
        resetElementOnLiveEdit
      },
      liveEdit: saveBeforeEdit
    })
```

As you can see, in profiles object in setState method i'm including **resetElementOnLiveEdit**.

The question is, how to include like i describe this variable in setState method, only if its not **NULL**?

Cause now i have null prop in state :(

Comment: *"Cause now i have null prop in state :("* What do you want instead?

Comment: Note: `if(!profile in liveEdit)` does not do what it seems like it does. It looks for a property called `"true"` or `"false"` in `liveEdit` and branches if it finds one.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder instead i dont want to add variable in setState method, or not to add any null to my object profiles

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you right with your note. in my expression i want to check if property profile exists in object liveEdit. if you have solution pls share it

Comment: Sorry, got called away. I've [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993162/how-to-check-if-variable-not-null-before-adding-it-as-object-property?noredirect=1#comment98635191_55993230) now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're breaking one of the primary rules of React: Because [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), if you're setting state based on existing state (`...this.state.profiles`), you **must** use the callback version of `setState` (so you aren't using stale state). So your code would be:

```
this.setState(({profiles}) => ({
  profiles: {
    ...profiles,
    [profile]: profileCopy,
    resetElementOnLiveEdit
  },
  liveEdit: saveBeforeEdit
}));
```

If you want to not have the property at all, your best bet is to separate it out:

```
this.setState(({profiles}) => {
  var newState = {
    profiles: {
      ...profiles,
      [profile]: profileCopy
    },
    liveEdit: saveBeforeEdit
  };
  if (resetElementOnLiveEdit !== null) {
    newState.profiles.resetElementOnLiveEdit = resetElementOnLiveEdit;
  }
  return newState;
});
```

But if you like, you can spread an object and pick either a blank one or one with the property:

```
this.setState(({profiles}) => ({
  profiles: {
    ...profiles,
    [profile]: profileCopy,
    ...(resetElementOnLiveEdit === null ? {} : {resetElementOnLiveEdit})
  },
  liveEdit: saveBeforeEdit
}));
```

In theory, that means you're creating an object, spreading it, and then throwing it away. But this isn't likely to be a critical performance path...

Comment: Crowder, can you pls help with this line of code? if(!profile in liveEdit) i want to check if profile property exist in liveEdit object with that line, and if not to do something

Comment: @WhoIsDT - `if (!profile in liveEdit)` is `if ( (!profile) in liveEdit)` which is going to check for a property called `"true"` or `"false" in `liveEdit`. to check that the property doesn't exist, you need `()`: `if (!(profile in liveEdit))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `profiles` object before the code and set it only if not null:

```js
const profiles = { 
  ...this.state.profiles,
  [profile]: profileCopy,
};
if (resetElementOnLiveEdit) {
  profiles.resetElementOnLiveEdit = resetElementOnLiveEdit;
}
this.setState({
  profiles,
  liveEdit: saveBeforeEdit
});
```

or, if you must do it in a one liner, you can:

```js
this.setState({
  profiles: {
    ...this.state.profiles,
    [profile]: profileCopy,
    ...(resetElementOnLiveEdit ? { resetElementOnLiveEdit } : {})
  },
  liveEdit: saveBeforeEdit
})
```